# Explanation of Sahih Muslim 5:161 (587)

Tags: dajjal

[Al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7129), [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:587) and [Sunan An-Nasai](https://sunnah.com/nasai:5517) report:

"I heard the Messenger of Allah ﷺ seeking refuge from the trial of Ad-Dajjal in prayer."

Other Hadith refer to Ad-Dajjal as a false prophet that would appear in future, before the coming of the Messiahﷺ and the resurrection of Muhammadﷺ, and the final trial (which is in the Hand of God).

For me, the questions arises

As Muhammad ﷺ died before the predicted time and woud be resurrected later, what should be his concern?

How can it be explained that Muhammad ﷺ seeked refuge from the trial of Ad-Dajjal in prayer?

Comment: Please elaborate, what needs explaining?

Comment: I have added it to the question.

Comment: Second edit: I have resolved one misunderstanding as the English translation trial originates in فِتْنَةِ , which is temptation. but the other remains.

Comment: I think it means that he'd make dua asking Allah for protection from Dajjal

Comment: Resurrection of Muhammad (SAW)? What are you talking about?

Comment: @TheZ I mean the near-end-of-time event, with the appearance of the Messiah.

Comment: @Jeschu Never heard of such a thing. Maybe you're confusing it with the concept of the Mahdi who is a prophecied descendant of the Prophet who will become the leader of the Muslims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either 1) Dajjal was definitely supposed to appear only after the Prophet or 2) it was possible for him to appear in the Prophet's lifetime.

If the first, maybe the Prophet was not informed of that at the time he made this dua. If he was also informed of it when he made the dua, maybe he did it to set an example for his people.

If the second, Dajjal could have appeared in the Prophet's time if Allah wanted, but Allah decided to delay him. The Prophet was reported saying: "If Dajjal appears while I am with you, I will defend you against him. But if he appears after I die, then everyone of you is his own defender" ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2937a)) indicating that at least at the time the statement was said Dajjal and Jesus could possibly have come in his time.

Furthermore, Ibn Sayyad being suspected as the Dajjal by the Prophet and companions indicates they weren't sure (at least at the time) that Dajjal would only appear after the Prophet.

Maybe a combination of the two occurred: the Prophet was originally not told Dajjal would be after him so he made the dua then he was told and he continued to make it to set an example.

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 1):

The Prophet supplicated with this dua as a ritualistic act of worship and to teach the Muslims, as we imitate his actions. He himself was safe from the fitnah of Dajjal, even if Dajjal were to appear in his lifetime. Because prophet's are infallible and because he had already been informed of his salvation in the future and afterlife - which precludes being misled by Dajjal.

> وللآخرة خير لك من الأولى ولسوف يعطيك ربك فترضى
>
> And the Hereafter is better for you than the first [life]. And your Lord is going to give you, and you will be satisfied.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 93:4](https://quran.com/93/4?translations=20)</sup>

---

**Ref:**

> فإن قلت: رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم آمن من فتنة الدجال ونحوها فما الفائدة فيه؟ قلت نفس الدعاء عبادة كقوله اللهم اغفر لي مع كونه مغفورا له أو هو لتعليم الأمة
>
> <sup>— [الكواكب الدراري في شرح صحيح البخاري](https://shamela.ws/book/13605/1486)</sup>

> واستعاذته - صلى الله عليه وسلم - مما ذكر؛ تعليم لأمته، وإلا فهو معصوم من ذلك. أو إنه سلك به مسلك التواضع، وإظهار العبودية، والخوف منه، والافتقار إليه، وإنما استعاذ من فتنة الدجال مع أنه لم يدركه؛ لأن فائدته، كما علم تعليم أمته
>
> <sup>— [منحة الباري بشرح صحيح البخاري](https://shamela.ws/book/18106/1198)</sup>